# UWP C# Textbox count of lines

Tags: c#, .net, string, textbox, uwp

I have an UWP C# app with a textbox. I'd like to know how many lines is in this textbox. How can I do it?
This is my textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textarea"
             IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"
             Margin="12 0 12 0"
             BorderThickness="0"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             AcceptsReturn="True" 
             IsReadOnly="False"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
             KeyDown="textarea_KeyDown" 
             TextChanged="textarea_TextChanged" KeyUp="textarea_KeyUp"/>
```

I've tried to get lines using `"\n"` or `Environment.NewLine`, but it doesn't work. I know about `RichEditBox`, but I want to use the `TextBox`. Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: I have already solved it, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. I found an ascii code for the new line in the textbox. Here is my solution:

```
private int LineCount()
    {
        int asciiLine = 13;
        char line = (char)asciiLine;
        int numLines = textarea.Text.Split(line).Length;
        return numLines;
    }
```

Comment: int numLines = textarea.Text.Split('\n').Length; is not working for me.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, but only thing, what works for me is this.

Comment: Doesn't count wrapped lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I recently handled something similar - in case helpful to anyone here (BTW if someone has something slicker please chime in):

```
    public static Int32 GetLineCountFromString(string text)
    {
        Int32 lineCount = 0;            
        try
        {
            string[] lines = Regex.Split(text.Trim(), "\r\n");
            lineCount = lines.Length;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
        return lineCount;   
    }
```